# Cannot log in with iPad anymore

Tags: bug, login, ipad

Since couple of days I cannot log in via iPad anymore. First, I thought it might be a temporary technical issue, but the problem still persists.

If I click on 'sign in' and click the 'log in via Google' button, the button shows some animation that it was clicked, however nothing happens then - no log in.

I also made sure that I am logged in into gmail on Safari.

Anyone has similar problems? I am curious if this is a individual problem with my Safari browser on the iPad, or if it became a general problem.

Comment: I'm logged in with an iPad right now, so it doesn't look like a general problem.

Comment: Are you using private browsing mode? I always have the problem when using private browsing mode.

Comment: Thanks, it was the private browsing option that caused the trouble. That's weird, I didn't change any settings recently, and it worked before...

Answer (score 1):

Private browsing option of the browser was causing the problem, getting out of private mode might solve the issue.

(Originally posted in a [comment by OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177639/cannot-log-in-with-ipad-anymore#comment534910_177639))

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and the fix was to reset all Safari settings (browsing history, cookies, etc). After that, it worked fine. I assume it's a bad auth cookie that mobile Safari is caching, but I never investigated much after it started working again.